# std::vector and memory error when resizing

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a structure defined like this:

```
struct Edge
{
    int u, v;   // vertices

    Edge() { }
    Edge(int u, int v)
    {
        this->u = u;
        this->v = v;
    }
};
```

and a class field defined like

```
vector<Edge> solution;
```

In one of the methods I'm creating new `Edge`s and pushing them into the vector like this (a huge simplification of my real code, but the problem still exists):

```
solution.push_back(Edge(1, 2));
solution.push_back(Edge(3, 4));
solution.push_back(Edge(5, 6));
solution.push_back(Edge(7, 8));
solution.push_back(Edge(9, 10));
solution.push_back(Edge(11, 12));
solution.push_back(Edge(13, 14)); // adding 7th element; the problem occurs here
```

When the last `push_back` is executing, I'm getting an error window in Visual Studio's debug mode

> [AppName] has triggered a breakpoint.

and the debugger goes to `malloc.c`, to the end of `_heap_alloc` function. Before this 7th line, the vector seems to work properly. I can see all the elements in the debugger. It seems that the vector has a problem reallocating itself (expanding its size).

What's interesting, if I put this before all the pushing back:

```
solution.reserve(7);
```

, the 7th edge is added properly. What's even more interesting, trying to reserve space for more than 22 elements also causes the mentioned error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug it? The rest of the application doesn't use so much memory, so I can't believe the heap is full.

---

More code, on request. It's a rather sloppy implementation of 2-approximation algorithm for Metric Travelling Salesman's Problem. It first creates a minimum spanning tree, then adds vertices (just indices) to the `partialSolution` vector in the DFS order.

```
void ApproxTSPSolver::Solve()
{
    // creating a incidence matrix
    SquareMatrix<float> graph(noOfPoints);

    for (int r=0; r<noOfPoints; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<noOfPoints; c++)
        {
            if (r == c)
                graph.SetValue(r, c, MAX);
            else
                graph.SetValue(r, c, points[r].distance(points[c]));
        }
    }

    // finding a minimum spanning tree
    spanningTree = SquareMatrix<bool>(noOfPoints);

    // zeroeing the matrix
    for (int r=0; r<noOfPoints; r++)
        for (int c=0; c<noOfPoints; c++)
            spanningTree.SetValue(r, c, false);

    bool* selected = new bool[noOfPoints];
    memset(selected, 0, noOfPoints*sizeof(bool));
    selected[0] = true; // the first point is initially selected

    float min;
    int minR, minC;

    for (int i=0; i<noOfPoints - 1; i++)
    {
        min = MAX;

        for (int r=0; r<noOfPoints; r++)
        {
            if (selected[r] == false)
                continue;

            for (int c=0; c<noOfPoints; c++)
            {
                if (selected[c] == false && graph.GetValue(r, c) < min)
                {
                    min = graph.GetValue(r, c);
                    minR = r;
                    minC = c;
                }
            }
        }

        selected[minC] = true;
        spanningTree.SetValue(minR, minC, true);
    }

    delete[] selected;

    // traversing the tree
    DFS(0);

    minSol = 0.0f;

    // rewriting the solution to the solver's solution field
    for (int i=0; i<noOfPoints - 1; i++)
    {
        solution.push_back(Edge(partialSolution[i], partialSolution[i + 1]));
        minSol += points[partialSolution[i]].distance(points[partialSolution[i + 1]]);
    }

    solution.push_back(Edge(partialSolution[noOfPoints - 1], partialSolution[0]));
    minSol += points[partialSolution[noOfPoints - 1]].distance(points[partialSolution[0]]);

    cout << endl << minSol << endl;

    solved = true;
}

void ApproxTSPSolver::DFS(int vertex)
{
    bool isPresent = std::find(partialSolution.begin(), partialSolution.end(), vertex)
        != partialSolution.end();

    if (isPresent == false)
        partialSolution.push_back(vertex); // if I comment out this line, the error doesn't occur

    for (int i=0; i<spanningTree.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        if (spanningTree.GetValue(vertex, i) == true)
            DFS(i);
    }
}


class ApproxTSPSolver : public TSPSolver
{
    vector<int> partialSolution;
    SquareMatrix<bool> spanningTree;
    void DFS(int vertex);

public:
    void Solve() override;
};
```

---

from `main.cpp`:

```
TSPSolver* solver;
    string inputFilePath, outputFilePath;

    // parsing arguments
    if (ArgParser::CmdOptionExists(argv, argv + argc, "/a"))
    {
        solver = new ApproxTSPSolver();
    }
    else if (ArgParser::CmdOptionExists(argv, argv + argc, "/b"))
    {
        solver = new BruteForceTSPSolver();
    }
    else
    {
        solver = new BranchAndBoundTSPSolver();
    }

    inputFilePath = ArgParser::GetCmdOption(argv, argv + argc, "/i");
    outputFilePath = ArgParser::GetCmdOption(argv, argv + argc, "/s");

    solver->LoadFromFile(inputFilePath);

    Timer timer;
    timer.start();
    solver->Solve();
    timer.stop();

    cout << timer.getElapsedTime();
```

A part of TSPSolver.c:

```
TSPSolver::TSPSolver()
{
    points = NULL;
    solved = false;
}

TSPSolver::~TSPSolver()
{
    if (points)
        delete[] points;
}

void TSPSolver::LoadFromFile(string path)
{
    ifstream input(path);
    string line;
    int nodeID;
    float coordX, coordY;
    bool coords = false;

    minX = numeric_limits<float>::max();
    maxX = numeric_limits<float>::min();
    minY = numeric_limits<float>::max();
    maxY = numeric_limits<float>::min();

    while (input.good())
    {
        if (coords == false)
        {
            getline(input, line);

            if (line == "NODE_COORD_SECTION")
            {
                coords = true;
            }
            else if (line.find("DIMENSION") != string::npos)
            {
                int colonPos = line.find_last_of(":");
                noOfPoints = stoi(line.substr(colonPos + 1));
#ifdef _DEBUG
                cout << noOfPoints << " points" << endl;
#endif

                // allocating memory for this amount of points
                points = new Point[noOfPoints];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input >> nodeID >> coordX >> coordY;

            points[nodeID - 1].X = coordX;
            points[nodeID - 1].Y = coordY;

            minX = min(minX, coordX);
            maxX = max(maxX, coordX);
            minY = min(minY, coordY);
            maxY = max(maxY, coordY);

            if (nodeID == noOfPoints)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Perhaps you have an error somewhere else in you program, e.g. writing to an invalid memory address.

Comment: Is your vector 7 elements long in your actual code, or more like thousands or millions?

Comment: @Cyber, in the actual code, the vector is initially empty. So the error occurs when trying to add 7th element to the vector.

Comment: @Danvil, that's right - after commenting out the whole code that's before using vector, there's no error. So I'm not questioning that there's a bug in my code. I'm wondering how I can find it. Are there any tools that could help me locating the invalid memory address write?

Comment: @PiotrK Visual Studio allows you to set up "data breakpoints" - specify the address of a variable (or just any address, really), and the debugger will break execution when a write to this address occurs. It slows down execution to a crawl, but it might help.

Comment: @PiotrK: You can try this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: Can you see a backtrace (i.e. called functions stack)? It should show you exactly which line of your code introduces this problem.

Comment: In MVSExpress 2012 there's no error. Are you compiling to regular Win32?

Comment: @MichałGóral, yes, but it doesn't tell me much: http://i.imgur.com/8JMUlMo.png . The marked call is just my call of `push_back`, nothing special about it, as you can see in the code. I guess I'll have to try the tool Danvil proposed.

Comment: @IosifMurariu, you probably won't reproduce my error. It's specific to my situation, it's not `vector`'s fault. I already know what part of my code causes the error, but don't know why yet. Yes, it's Win32.

Comment: please use `Edge(int uu, int vv): u(uu), v(vv) {}`. It's more efficient than your current constructor.

Comment: I've kind of isolated the problem. I have another vector `partialSolution` I push back some data to, just before putting data to the actual `solution` vector. If I comment out any pushing back to `paritalSolution`, there error doesn't occur...

Comment: try the debugger, it will not disappoint

Comment: You don't show the definition of partialSolution or anything about its setup. Given your symptoms that is kind of important.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, it's just defined as a field in the class, see at the end of the code I pasted. I assume the constructor of `vector` is called. To be honest, I haven't seen C++ for a few years.

Comment: also missing details about `points`.  BTW if you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you'll get a quick answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, it's very hard to construct one. The behavior depends on the input data, and I can see no relation between e.g. size of the matrices I allocate and the maximum capacity of the vector.

Comment: @PiotrK I am more interested in the bit in `main` that sets up the object.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I've pasted some more code.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a comment then an answer, but the space is too limited.

If you are on windows, try [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It might detect wrong memory access.

Another way of detecting such access is to reseve empty char arrays initialized to 0.

Open your class where the vector is declared and declare a char array of let's say 64 chars before and after your vector and initialize them to 0!.
Then break into your vector code, where the error is generated and check the contents of those padding arrays. If they are filled, somebody writes more that it should.

A way to locate the "malicious" access (at least in VC++) is to set a data breakpoint writing in your padding arrays and check the callstack then.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The 'zeros' method didn't return anything interesting, both arrays are still filled with 0s. I can't set data breakpoints which 'scan' more than 4 bytes ahead, and this render them basically useless. I'm getting this error: "The breakpoint cannot be set. The hardware does not support monitoring the requested number of bytes.". I have to try the tools you guys proposed, maybe some of them will tell me something.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing out-of-bounds accesses on `points` in various places, e.g. this one:

```
input >> nodeID >> coordX >> coordY;
points[nodeID - 1].X = coordX;
```

What if input failed, or the value is out of range?

I would suggest removing all uses of `new` and `delete` and `[]`from your code; e.g. assuming `points` is `int *points;` then replace it with `std::vector<int> points`. Change all `[]` accesses to be `.at()` and catch exceptions.   Disable copying on all classes that don't have correct copy semantics.

Then you can be more certain that it is not a memory allocation error, copying error, or out-of-bounds access (which are strong candidates for explaining your symptoms).

This would also fix the problem that `TSPSolver` currently does not have correct copy semantics.

It would be very useful to make a SSCCE.  You mention that there is "a lot of input", try reducing the input as small as you can but still have the problem occur. An SSCCE can include input data so long as it is a manageable size that you can post. Currently you show too much code but not enough, as they say. The problem is still lurking somewhere you haven't posted yet.